# Is it possible to call useSWR from outside a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering, swr

My code basically looks like this:

```
export default  function myComponent() {
    async function getResults(myParams ){


      const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/blah>myParams=' + myParams );    
  
      //do some other stuff...

      return data;
    }

  useEffect(() => {
      let myParams = someLogicToGetDynamicParams();

      myresults=  getResults(myParams );

  }, [abc]);
  

   //...
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I understand that I should put useSWR inside of useEffect, but suppose my logic is getting long, and I want to refactor it.  Does this mean I'm not allowed to refactor useSWR out into its own function (like my example above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply destruct `data` and `error` outside the function and use them inside it.

```js
export default  function myComponent() {
    const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/blah');

    async function getResults(){
      //do some other stuff using 'data' and 'error'...
      return data;
    }

  useEffect(() => {
      let myresults = getResults();
  }, [abc]);
   //...
}
```

and if you want to make

```js
const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/blah');
```

happen inside a function, you have to name this latter starting with the prefix 'use' to consider it as a hook

```js
async function useGetResults(){
   const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/blah')
   //do some other stuff using 'data' and 'error'...
  return data;
}
```

this should compile without errors, but the first approach is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I might have oversimplified my code example.  I just made an edit.  Inside of useEffect, I have some code to get the params (eg, from a form), then pass the params into getResults.  So, I can't put useSWR inside of a a function.  I'll need it inside getResults(myParams).

Comment: Ok, so I'm reading that useSWR can't be called inside of other hooks.  They can only be called at the start of the function component.  src:  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level   Therefore, I think your first solution is the only answer.  Only thing, if I want the url to by dynamic, so I'm not sure how I'd get that to work.

Comment: @NL3294 ah! I see now. what you are trying to do is not possible, you cannot call a hook from inside `useEffect` you should make `someLogicToGetDynamicParams()` executes inside the body of your function component

Comment: ah, thanks for confirming.  I thought it would be nice to refactor my logic into a function, but I guess it's just not possible.

Comment: @NL3294 one solution I can think of is to create a state to store `myParams` when `someLogicToGetDynamicParams()` is executed inside `useEffect` this will rerender the component then you get the new `{data,error}` based on the new `myParams` value

Answer (score 0):

`useSwr` is usually used if you are fetching frequently changed data. for example, you want to show the price of ethereum on your website, you should use `useSwr`.

```
const fetcher = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  // ?? will return second if json is undefined
  return json ?? null;
};

export const useGetData = (params) => {
  // construct URL here
  const URL= "base_url"+`${/prams}`
  const { data, ...rest } = useSWR(URL, fetcher, { refreshInterval: 10000 });
  
  return { myData: { data, ...rest } };
};
```

then you can call the above function in your component

```
export default  function myComponent({params}) {
    const {myData}=useGetData(params)
}
```

I passed `params` as prop, you could pass it from `getServerSideProps` or you could get them in `useEffect` and store them in `useState`.

`useSwr` itself a hook. hook means it is hooked into the react lifecycle. `useSwr` knows when to rerender the component. [from docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/advanced/performance)

> SWR deep compares data changes by default. If the data value isn’t
> changed, a re-render will not be triggered.